# Pasting a 2D array in a named range that is not rectangular

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to paste part of a 2D array into a range name than is a triangle, without looping over the lines and columns because it's too time consuming:

Here is a example:

```
Sub test2()
    Dim arr() As Double
    ReDim arr(1 To 4, 1 To 4)
    For i = 1 To 4
        For j = 1 To 4
            arr(i, j) = i + j
        Next j
    Next i
    
    'Worksheets("test").Range("A1:d4") = arr
     Worksheets("test").Range("TEST_TRIANGLE") = arr
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, the code doesn't do what I want : it actually fill the triangle only with the 1 column of the array

[image: This is what I get]

Whereas if I comment the last line and uncomment the one before:

[image: This is what I get]

The content of the triangle is correct, but unfortunately I also write in parts of the sheet that are filled with something else.

Does anybody know how I can achieve what I want ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What error do you get?  Also what is the range for "TEST_TRIANGLE"

Comment: Try with `Dim arr() As Variant` actually.

Comment: Hello @JohnAlexiou, I've just tried it but I obtained the same result

Comment: What is the result you are getting?

Comment: Hello @Nathan_Sav I don't have a error message, but the output I get is incorrect (between the first screen shot and the second, the values are different).
The range TEST_TRIANGLE is the grey triangle in the screenshots

Comment: @JohnAlexiou I If I put in my code ```Worksheets("test").Range("A1:d4") = arr ``` I get the same result as you, (the rectangle, which I don't want), and if I put ```Worksheets("test").Range("TEST_TRIANGLE") = arr ``` then it only writes in the triangle area, but the values are wrong

Answer (score 0):

First the results. I have a sheet with formulas, and I am overwriting a select non-rectangular area. The named range "TRIG" consists in the gray shaded cells.

[image: pic1]

In VBA, the range object contains several `Range().Areas` which is a list of sub-ranges each rectangular in shape. So I decided to go through each one, find out where they are located relative to the named range (two offsets `i1` and `j1` calculated below).

The loop through the elements of each sub-range and set the value.

```
Public Sub TestTrig()

    Dim arr() As Variant, x As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim i1 As Long, j1 As Long
    
    Dim r As Range, ra As Range
    Set r = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("TRIG")
    
    For Each ra In r.Areas
        i1 = ra.Row - r.Row
        j1 = ra.Column - r.Column
        If ra.Rows.Count > 1 Or ra.Columns.Count > 1 Then
            arr = ra.Value
            For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
                For j = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
                    arr(i, j) = 4 * (i - 1 + i1) + j + j1
                Next j
            Next i
            ra.Value = arr
        Else
            x = ra.Value
            x = 4 * (i1) + j1 + 1
            ra.Value = x
        End If
    Next
    
   

End Sub
```

Special care must be taken when only 1 cell is in the range, as the `.Value` *is not an array* but a scalar value. I used a variable `x` for this case.

Comment: John the problem is that I don't want my code to write in the lower part of the triangle (the values 6, 7 and 8)

Comment: ok, then just fill in all the values in the array.

Comment: But won't it overwrite the content if the cells bellow the triangle when I execute the code ? like in C4 or D4 for example ? I have formulas in those cells that I want to keep

Comment: Check the edits now. I read the values before setting the new ones.

Comment: Nice idea indeed ! you think I can store the formula instead of the value within the array ?

Comment: @Personalj123 - unfortunately not, it overwrites the cells value property which kills any formulas. I'll do another try now that I understand the problem.

Comment: This does not feel as elegant as  I wanted. You might as well write the cells directly, instead of trying to read an array into memory and write back. Nevertheless, see the next iteration of my answer above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, like me you ended up doing 2 loops within one another. I don't feel stupid now that I see that other people come to the same conclusion :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try going about it a different way, if you are looping the segments of the triangle in the first place, you can build a segment and stack them with a vertical origin.  This generates, without overtyping, a triangle, with the cells A1-A4 and A1-D1 being the height and base.  You can play about to the way it builds, but building it from the top or bottom.  `q` is just to put something in the array.

```
Sub tri()

Const arrayNum As Integer = 4

Dim arrSeg() As Double

For i = 1 To arrayNum
    
    ReDim arrSeg(1 To arrayNum - i + 1)

    For l = 1 To arrayNum - i + 1
    
        arrSeg(l) = q
        q = q + 1
        
    Next l

    Range("a1").Offset(0, i - 1).Resize(UBound(arrSeg), 1).Value = Application.Transpose(arrSeg)
    
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @Nathan_Sav for the Answer Nathan that a nice way to avoid doing 2 loops but only one. I think I ll test this solution to see if its saving some time compared to the code with 2 loops

Answer (score 0):

**Slice** the existing array `arr` row wise via `Application.Index(arr, i, 0)` and write the slices to sheet by *resizing* the receiving target rows at the same time:

```
Dim i As Long, ii As Long
ii = UBound(arr)
For i = LBound(arr) To ii
    Sheet1.Range("A1").Offset(i - 1).Resize(1, ii - i + 1) = Application.Index(arr, i, 0)
Next
```

Comment: Thanks @T.M. I'll try that